# Injecting a custom stylesheet into a site via Chrome Devtools

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Here's the plan: I'm trying to customize a site. I want to create and edit a CSS file locally (on my *own* text editor) and inject it into the page using the new Workspace and Filesystem features in DevTools.

These two features seem to work quite well, except they only allow you to *map* certain local files to network files.

I want to *create* a *new* file and inject *that* into the page, not modify an existing (loaded) stylesheet.

Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Even if it's possible, you'll have to open DevTools every time you open said website for stylesheet to change.

Answer (score 0):

U can use the chrome extentions for that...create an extention and everytime a page loads you can add that to it.I had done it earlier,modifying the contents of www.imdb.com for a extention of mine called Movie mapper,unfortunately Chrome store removed it after 1 yr.You want the code ? I can share

Comment: If you like, you could open-source the code into a place like GitHub for everyone to see and benefit.

Comment: Yeah thts a good idea...i will do that..bt it might take sometime..i lost my githug password :( but i will open source the code.You need it?urgently?

Comment: I'm looking more for a DevTools specific hack, without any extensions. Good idea, though I'd rather just use userscripts instead of extensions for that.